# Stop cron sending mail for backup script?

Tags: cron, email, backup

I have set up a backup script to back up world data on my Minecraft server hourly using cron, but because the worlds being constantly edited by players, tar was telling me that files changed while they were read. I added --ignore-command-error to the tar in the script and that suppresses any errors when I run it manually, however cron still sends a mail message saying that files were changed while being read, and ends up flooding my mail because it's run once an hour. Anyone know how to fix this? This is the script:

```
filename=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
cd /home/minecraft/Server/
for world in survival survival_nether survival_the_end creative superflat
do
if [ ! -d "/home/minecraft/backups/$world" ]; then
mkdir /home/minecraft/backups/$world
fi
find /home/minecraft/backups/$world -mtime +1 -delete
tar --ignore-command-error -c $world/ | nice -n 10 pigz -9 > /home/minecraft/backups/$world/$filename.tar.gz
done
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Cron will attempt to send an email with any output that may have occurred when the command was run. From cron's man page:

> When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the
>   crontab (or to the user specified in the MAILTO environment variable
>   in the crontab, if such exists).  Any job output can also be sent to
>   syslog  by  using the -s option.

So to disable it for a specific crontab entry just capture all of the commands output and either direct it to a file or to `/dev/null`.

```
30 * * * * notBraiamsBackup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: D: using my example!

Comment: @Braiam - sorry I was feeling lazy and didn't feel like typing it up. I would've typed the same thing anyway 8-).

Comment: @Braiam - is that better? 8-).

Comment: Works great, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that in my CentOS 7, with `crontab` not `cron`, `-s` means `selinux context`.....

Comment: The `2>&1` deserves explanation. https://superuser.com/questions/71428/what-does-21-do-in-command-line

Answer (score 21):

Instead of piping everything to `/dev/null` (which may leave you without a clue of what happened if something goes wrong), you can pipe your scripts to log files like this:

```
30 * * * * backup.sh > ~/logs/backup.log
```

And to stop getting mails, just set the `MAILTO` variable to an empty string at the beginning of your crontab file:

```
MAILTO=""
```

Comment: I'd rather write `30 * * * * backup.sh >> ~/logs/backup.log 2>&1`

Comment: I have a lot of crontabs, and some commands are very long. So I think this is the nicer and command-shorter way.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want mails for an specific cron task, you can simply add `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the line:

```
30 * * * * backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I choose this way: you lost track of everything, but neatly.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following to your *gnu tar* command: **--warning=no-file-changed**

That will suppress all the "*%s: file changed as we read it*" messages. And by using this solution (and not redirecting everything to /dev/null), you will still be able to get error messages when stuff really goes wrong..

---

With the *--warning* flag you can enable and disable a lot of different messages that *tar* prints. Here's the relevant part of the manual with all the keywords you can use: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_27.html.

Note: by adding "*no-*" in front of a keyword, the message will be suppressed.